# Unable to build Spring Tool Suite Quick Start

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Having loaded the Consuming REST Quick Start without any apparent problem, I am unable to build the project.

Following is the error message from Spring Tool Suite:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo.spring.io/libs-release/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.1.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.1.8.RELEASE.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.1.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.1.8.RELEASE.pom
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.springframework:gs-consuming-rest:0.1.0 (/Users/matthewbrown/Documents/workspace/gs-consuming-rest-initial/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.1.8.RELEASE from/to spring-releases (http://repo.spring.io/libs-release): connect timed out and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 10, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Comment: Well the POM exists. Can you reach the following URL from that machine: http://repo.spring.io/libs-release/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.1.8.RELEASE/

Comment: Yes, I can reach that URL via both browser and curl.

Comment: Okay, figured it out - thanks to Alan's clear, straightforward response. Based on your feedback I started looking into proxy settings, etc. My machine is complicated due to security settings at this client. They have proxy servers, so whenever I jump on or off their network, I have scripts that have to switch up the settings. It looks like I need to have it also swap out my ~/.m2/settings.xml file with another version for the alternative usage scenario. ...it was that I had set up proxies in that file. Once I switched off the proxies, Spring Tool Suite/eclipse started working - for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue turned out to be the ~/.m2/settings.xml file. It has a set of proxies defined for use on certain office networks at my client. Disabling these proxies allows Spring Tool Suite to work again.

Now for how to make the swap between on and off network more easily attained...